# Creating UIView in xib, interface builder and without using UIViewController to attach it to the window

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm new to views and view controllers.....i was wondering if there is a way to create a view(UIView) using xib (i.e, I have all three files .m, .h and .xib of the UIView) and I attach it to the window like [window addSubview:myView];??

all the examples I have seen till now have used UIViewController to load the view using xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this, but here is what you can do:
In `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` from AppDelegate class, load your custom view

```
CustomView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then add view to the window

```
[self.window addSubview:view];
```

That's it.

Comment: It works and i get the ObjectAtIndex thing.....but why does owner set to nil does the job? shoudnt the owner be the view.m?

Comment: if you set view's 'custom class' from the xib, then 'loadNibNamed' doesn't require a owner, so you can pass nil.